# Problem upgrading N1 to Android 2.3

Tags: updates, nexus-one, unrooting

I have a once-rooted Nexus one. Since then I unrooted it to enable automatic upgrades, and currently have a stock 2.2.

I got the notification to upgrade my OS (to 2.3 I assume), but after my phone restarts, I am presented with the following text in the recovery screen:

```
Build : RA-nexus-v1.5.3
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
E:No signature (8 files)
E:Verification failed
Installation aborted.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: 2.3 isn't out for any phone right now except the Nexus S (officially, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a bad download.  I'd delete it if you can and try again, or download and upgrade manually.  For 2.2.1, try following [this post at androidandme](http://androidandme.com/2010/09/news/android-2-2-1-hits-the-nexus-one-manually-install-it-now/).  If it was 2.3 you might want to wait, Google has said it wouldn't be released for the N1 till after the holidays ([example](http://www.gizmocrunch.com/android/4278-nexus-one-android-gingerbread-update)) so it might have been a mistake.

Comment: I was just guessing that the suggested upgrade is to 2.3, it could be just a minor patch. Do you know how I do a clean update manually, and where I can find the latest official image?

Comment: Makes sense.  I'm not sure how to clean out the update, but I've updated my answer with how to manually get 2.2.1.